# Jenkins HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have updated Jenkins version with k8s pod, I download jenkins war and exec to pod then I replace war file. The last I restart pod (kubectl delete pod ....). In this process, I have disabled Jenkins login by change tab useSecurity in config.xml file to **false**.
I access Jenkins GUI => Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security and Enabled login **Logged-in users can do anything** and then I re-login. I got this error.

[The error:]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFqPu.png

Old Jenkins version : 2.121.3

New Jenkins version : 2.235

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Crumb is Jenkins way of CSRF protection. As of [version 2.222](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.222/) this protection has been enabled by default. The proper way of working with the CSRF crumbs is documented in [CSRF protection explained](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained).

But since you are running without any security at all, you probably want to just disable CSRF protection at all:

> Set the system property `hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION` to true on startup to disable CSRF protection as well as the configuration UI for it. This is an unsupported option and may be removed in the future.

Comment: I set the system property hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION to true and it works. Thanks.

Comment: `hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION = true`
Run the above on the "Manage Jenkins > Script Console" 

Thanks @Joep

Comment: Just adding that the [Jenkins docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/#disabling-csrf-protection) explain this quite well and [disabling CSRF](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/#disabling-csrf-protection) is also listed there